# How insert content containing chinese characters into mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a small project. And I encounter a problem.
 When I insert data to database. It raise error same as: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA8\xAB\xA4\xEF\xBC...' for column...."

\xF0\xA8\xAB\xA4\xEF\xBC is ASCII-8BIT form and it's "" in utf-8 form. "" is chinese word.
I want to save that data to database. My idea is: convert ASCII-8BIT charactors to utf-8 charactor or remove chinese word before saving (bad way). But I can't find anyways to do them.
Can you help  me. Thanks for reading my question. Have a nice day.!

Ps: On some articles mention to way that change data type of column on table of database. But truly, I don't want to change database structure.

Comment: You can change the mysql column type to varbinary and store the ASCII-8BIT form as it is.

Comment: I knew this way through some posts. But I don't want use this way, because it do change database structure. I added some words above. Thanks for your support.